# how to use module factory to create objects and manipulate the dom in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, closures

I have this HTML code:

```html
<label for="AccountName">Account Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="mytext">
<label for="Deposit">Deposit: </label>
<input type="text" class="deposit" id="deposit">
<button type="submit" id="createAccount" onclick="createAccount()">Create new Account</button>
<textarea name="mytextarea" id="mytextarea" cols="140" rows="20"></textarea>
```

...and I wrote some code in JavaScript to get values from the input fields and construct `account` object from it and add those objects to `accountInfoList` which is a list. And finally I want to update the content of `mytextarea` with the `accountInfoList`. Sample run looks like this:

[image: sample output]

The JavaScript code I wrote is:

```
var accountInfoList = [];

const makeCounter = function() {
  let name = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  let balance = document.getElementById('deposit').value;

  function createAccount(AccountName, AccountBalance) {
    this.AccountName = AccountName;
    this.AccountBalance = AccountBalance;
  }

  var account = createAccount(name, balance);

  accountInfoList.push(account);

}

// document.getElementById('createAccount').onclick = createAccount;

function createAccount() {
  makeCounter();
  // console.log(account1);
  // const account2 = makeCounter(a)
  // accountInfoList.push(account1);
  console.log(typeof accountInfoList)
  for (var i = 0; i < accountInfoList.length; i++) {
    console.log("Account Name: " + accountInfoList[i].AccountName + "Balance: " + accountInfoList[i].balance);
  }
  // document.getElementById('mytextarea').value = accountInfoList[0].name;

}
```

...which doesn't seem to be working. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally come to the solution after long hours of debugging the script:

```
var accountInfoList = [];

const makeCounter = function() {
  let name = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  console.log(name);
  let balance = document.getElementById('deposit').value;
  console.log(balance);

  var account = new Account(name, balance);

  accountInfoList.push(account);

  console.log(typeof accountInfoList);
  console.log(accountInfoList.length);

}


class Account {
  constructor(name, balance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
  }
}

function createAccount() {
  makeCounter();
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < accountInfoList.length; i++) {
    text += "Account name: " + accountInfoList[i].name + "  " + "Balance: " + accountInfoList[i].balance + "\n";
  }

  document.getElementById('mytextarea').value = text;

}
```